# rgbdslam (fuerte and 12.04) Cannot locate rosdep definition for [opencv2.3]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i,m using fuerte in 12.04 .i have followed this tutorial [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#RGB-D_SLAM_for_Non-ROS_Users) . i am having the problem in "rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg" . following error occurs

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [opencv2.3]

i haev already installed "opencv2" package , still having this problem. i hope somebody will  help. i had posted the same problem few weeks back but nobody answered.
thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57547/rgbdslam-(fuerte-and-12.04)--cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Bopencv2.3%5D/) by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is weird. Here is what I have installed (output from `aptitude search opencv|grep ^i`:

Edit: The following is probably irrelevant, as the upper two seem to be relicts of my electric installation!

```
i A libopencv2.3-bin                - OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision)      
i A ros-electric-vision-opencv      - opencv                                    
i A ros-fuerte-opencv2              - OpenCV                                    
i A ros-fuerte-vision-opencv        - opencv
```

If you lack any of those, try installing it.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-03-09**:
thanks for help Felix . i have "libopencv2.3-bin" and "ros-electric-vision-opencv" missing . i hav tried installing it bt the packages are not available in ubuntu 12.04 i guess. do i have to downgrade from 12.04 to 11.10 to make it run?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-03-16**:
No, I have it running on 12.04 and 12.10. These are probably relicts of my electric installation then.

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-03-16**:
thanks Felix. i have installed it in my other laptop. its working fine now